# Where to ask in order to identify a book

Tags: support, site-recommendation

When I was young I was reading a book about physics. The book had a white cover with green text. The information in the book was partly that if you shoot an arrow from the back a train then that will be an example of a relative motion. In particular I am certain that the book mentioned a poem which was in style

> If I could dye me whyskers green so that they could not be seen ..

I'm also quite certain that there was an example of physics described in the same book, describing two lightbulbs which are emitting light next to each other inside a closed box with the question if the reader thinks that any shadow will appear on the inside on the box. The book also described the Michelson-Morley experiment if I remember correctly. Is there any way for me to get more information about the memory I have?

Comment: That line is taken from a song in the book Through the Looking Glass https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haddocks%27_Eyes The best site to ask seems to be https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic They take "Story and quote identification questions"

Comment: Related (Physics Meta): *[Are book/reference identification questions on topic?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12955)*. Is it a coincidence they were posted within 17 minutes of each other?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q, nope. I've seen this question and wanted to answer on it based on Physics SE policies/guidance. However, it was unclear to me. Hence, my question there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question would be best asked at [literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com), their [help centre](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says they accept

> Story and quote identification questions

Answer (score 1):

Different communities have different rules on, so-called, *identification questions*. Some have specific tags and guidance for them, and some prohibit them explicitly.

In this case, it is a special type of identification: *reference identification*.

[As per this discussion on Physics SE Meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12955/152812), such a question might be on-topic on Physics SE with the tag ["*specific-reference*"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-reference). My own judgment would be: the more the book you are looking for corresponds to a specialized physics reference, the more the question is likely to be well-received. This paragraph strictly talks about books on physics.

---

In general, for book/reference identification, consult the guidance of the thematic community, check relevant tags ("resource recommendation", "reference-request", etc), and check for the existing questions of such kind. Such questions might be on-topic. Otherwise, [a question on Literature SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) might be a viable choice as per @Mart Kirby's answer.